# How to know when `perf record -p <pid>` actually starts recording

Tags: perf

When I attach `perf` to a running process to trace some tracepoints, there is a lag of ~2sec between the `perf` command invocation and the actual recording. I know it, because if I send payload to the process too early (i.e. without waiting for 2sec after `perf` start), the execution doesn't appear in the recording.

My question is: is there a way to determine when `perf record` actually starts recording? Waiting for some arbitrary amount of time seems very brittle.

Comment: I'd expect it to only take tens of milliseconds to attach and program the HW perf counters, or set up software tracepoints.  I haven't used tracepoints, though, just HW perf events.  Are you sure you're not killing `perf` too quickly after your test in a way that doesn't let it flush buffers?  Like maybe 2 seconds gets event buffers close to full so the events from your test trigger a write-out?

Comment: I'm sending `SIGTERM` which triggers flushing before shutdown. The delay might be application-specific (pretty big, a lot of jitted code), but even tens of milliseconds delay could be too long if I were to execute the workload immediately afterward.
Using verbose mode helps, but even after the last message (`Synthesizing TSC conversion information`), there seems to be a delay in the order of tens of milliseconds before the recording actually begins.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was wondering.  Did you only ever try 2 seconds vs. right away?  Forking off a `perf record -p` and starting the workload can obviously race, but I'd guess that even 1 second is fine unless the system is swap thrashing or extremely high load average or some unusual situation.

Comment: I tried basically everything between 10ms and 2s. 1s sometimes succeeded, 2s was a reasonably stable time. But since it doesn't happen immediately (which is, of course, to be expected), I'd expect there to be some indicator of when perf actually starts recording.

Comment: What is your `perf record` command line? `perf script` will show some timestamps of events from perf.data. What is your kernel version? You cat try to do `strace -ttt perf record ...` to check what was done by perf before profiling start (it is somewhere around perf_event_open syscall or ioctl on the fd returned by it).